# Rails 5 nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-routes

I've three models `Project`, `Card` and `Task`.

**project** `has_many :cards`

**card** `has_many :tasks`

I've defined the route for building cards like following:

```
resources :projects, except: [:new, :edit, :show] do
    resources :cards do
      resources :tasks
    end
end
```

It'll create path for **cards** as: `projects/:project_id/cards/`

It'll create path for **tasks** as: `projects/:project_id/cards/:card_id/tasks`

What I need is: 
**Card** routes should be nested to **Project**. (which I currently have) and **Task** routes should nested to only **Card** like `/cards/:card_id/tasks` (which I need).

How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: card has many tasks?

Comment: @ray, yes. I've mentioned that on the question

Answer (score 1):

```
resources :projects, except: [:new, :edit, :show] do
    resources :cards
end
resources :cards do
    resources :tasks
end
```

This is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You can just do,

```
resources :projects, except: [:new, :edit, :show] do
    resources :cards
end
```

And further try with defining each route for task by,

```
get '/cards/:card_id/tasks', to: 'tasks#index'
```

I did not test but should work, Sad is you have to define it for each specific route.

Comment: In this way I need to manually add all the task routes like edit, create, update, destroy etc...

Comment: I wish there is better alternative but to make it work for temporary you can try above.